# Split text string in a data.table columns

Tags: r, data.table

I have a script that reads in data from a CSV file into a `data.table` and then splits the text in one column into several new columns. I am currently using the `lapply` and `strsplit` functions to do this. Here's an example:

```
library("data.table")
df = data.table(PREFIX = c("A_B","A_C","A_D","B_A","B_C","B_D"),
                VALUE  = 1:6)
dt = as.data.table(df)

# split PREFIX into new columns
dt$PX = as.character(lapply(strsplit(as.character(dt$PREFIX), split="_"), "[", 1))
dt$PY = as.character(lapply(strsplit(as.character(dt$PREFIX), split="_"), "[", 2))

dt 
#    PREFIX VALUE PX PY
# 1:    A_B     1  A  B
# 2:    A_C     2  A  C
# 3:    A_D     3  A  D
# 4:    B_A     4  B  A
# 5:    B_C     5  B  C
# 6:    B_D     6  B  D
```

In the example above the column `PREFIX` is split into two new columns `PX` and `PY` on the "_" character.

Even though this works just fine, I was wondering if there is a better (more efficient) way to do this using `data.table`. My real datasets have  >=10M+ rows, so time/memory efficiency becomes really important.

---

#### UPDATE:

Following @Frank's suggestion I created a larger test case and used the suggested commands, but the `stringr::str_split_fixed` takes a lot longer than the original method.

```
library("data.table")
library("stringr")
system.time ({
    df = data.table(PREFIX = rep(c("A_B","A_C","A_D","B_A","B_C","B_D"), 1000000),
                    VALUE  = rep(1:6, 1000000))
    dt = data.table(df)
})
#   user  system elapsed 
#  0.682   0.075   0.758 

system.time({ dt[, c("PX","PY") := data.table(str_split_fixed(PREFIX,"_",2))] })
#    user  system elapsed 
# 738.283   3.103 741.674 

rm(dt)
system.time ( {
    df = data.table(PREFIX = rep(c("A_B","A_C","A_D","B_A","B_C","B_D"), 1000000),
                     VALUE = rep(1:6, 1000000) )
    dt = as.data.table(df)
})
#    user  system elapsed 
#   0.123   0.000   0.123 

# split PREFIX into new columns
system.time ({
    dt$PX = as.character(lapply(strsplit(as.character(dt$PREFIX), split="_"), "[", 1))
    dt$PY = as.character(lapply(strsplit(as.character(dt$PREFIX), split="_"), "[", 2))
})
#    user  system elapsed 
#  33.185   0.000  33.191
```

So the `str_split_fixed` method takes about 20X times longer.

Comment: I think doing the operation outside of the data.table first might be better. If you use the `stringr` package, this is the command: `str_split_fixed(PREFIX,"_",2)`. I'm not answering because I haven't tested the speedup...Or, in one step: `dt[,c("PX","PY"):=data.table(str_split_fixed(PREFIX,"_",2))]`

Answer (score 161, accepted):

**Update:** From version 1.9.6 (on CRAN as of Sep'15), we can use the function `tstrsplit()` to get the results directly (and in a much more efficient manner):

```
require(data.table) ## v1.9.6+
dt[, c("PX", "PY") := tstrsplit(PREFIX, "_", fixed=TRUE)]
#    PREFIX VALUE PX PY
# 1:    A_B     1  A  B
# 2:    A_C     2  A  C
# 3:    A_D     3  A  D
# 4:    B_A     4  B  A
# 5:    B_C     5  B  C
# 6:    B_D     6  B  D
```

`tstrsplit()` basically is a wrapper for `transpose(strsplit())`, where `transpose()` function, also recently implemented, transposes a list. Please see `?tstrsplit()` and `?transpose()` for examples.

See history for old answers.

Comment: Thanks Arun. I hadn't thought of the method of first creating the list, then the index and then the columns as described in "a_spl". I always thought that doing everything in a single line was the best way. Just out of curiosity why does the index way work so much faster ?

Comment: @Arun, related to this question, what are some of the pitfalls you would see in a function like I've written here: https://gist.github.com/mrdwab/6873058 Basically, I've made use of `fread`, but to do so, I had to use a `tempfile` (which would seem like it would be a bottleneck) since it doesn't seem like `fread` has an equivalent to a `text` argument. Testing with this sample data, its performance is between your `a_spl` and `a_sub` approaches.

Comment: I was wondering how one could guess the number of columns on the LHS of := and dynamically create the names of the _new_ columns based on the grep tstrsplit occurences

Comment: Is there an efficient way to drop the original PREFIX column all at once using this approach?  I mean that might be faster or use less memory in process than chaining or doing it as a separate operation.

Comment: Trying to revive this old answer. How do you split by position (5 characters in c1, the rest in c2) directly in tstrsplit()? I made a turnaround using beforehand gsub to insert an empty space after 5 characters in my string, and then apply tstrsplit(x, " ", fixed=TRUE)

Answer (score 16):

I add answer for someone who do not use `data.table` **v1.9.5** and also want an one line solution.

```
dt[, c('PX','PY') := do.call(Map, c(f = c, strsplit(PREFIX, '-'))) ]
```

Answer (score 8):

Using `splitstackshape` package:

```
library(splitstackshape)
cSplit(df, splitCols = "PREFIX", sep = "_", direction = "wide", drop = FALSE)
#    PREFIX VALUE PREFIX_1 PREFIX_2
# 1:    A_B     1        A        B
# 2:    A_C     2        A        C
# 3:    A_D     3        A        D
# 4:    B_A     4        B        A
# 5:    B_C     5        B        C
# 6:    B_D     6        B        D
```

Answer (score 7):

We could try:

```
library(data.table)  
cbind(dt, fread(text = dt$PREFIX, sep = "_", header = FALSE))
    #    PREFIX VALUE V1 V2
    # 1:    A_B     1  A  B
    # 2:    A_C     2  A  C
    # 3:    A_D     3  A  D
    # 4:    B_A     4  B  A
    # 5:    B_C     5  B  C
    # 6:    B_D     6  B  D
```

Answer (score 4):

With tidyr the solution is:

```
separate(df,col = "PREFIX",into = c("PX", "PY"), sep = "_")
```

Comment: The question specifically asked for data.table solutions.  People working in this domain have already chosen data.table solutions in preference to tidyr solutions for a good reason relative to their challenges.

Comment: Other users have provided solutions with other libraries as well, I have just given a valid alternative, easy and fast.

Comment: Some new how-to may be found at http://hbiostat.org/rflow/manip.html#sec-manip-split

Comment: Sorry link is https://hbiostat.org/rflow/manip.html#sec-manip-text