# Split a column of strings into variable number of columns using data.table in R

Tags: r, string, data.table

I want to analyze many years of of Quicken home finance records. I exported a file to qif and used bank2csv program to render a csv. Within Quicken one can use a category (eg automobile, tax), subcategories (eg automobile:service, automobile:fuel) and tags (eg self, spouse, son). bank2csv renders the categories:subcategories/tag as a concatenated string. I want to instead put the category in a category column, subcategory in a subcategory column and put whatever tags in the tag column. I saw [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18154556/r-split-text-string-in-a-data-table-columns) but alas that worked by`strsplit` then `unlist` and then indexing each element so that it could be written to the correct place by assignment. That will not work here since sometimes there is no tag and sometimes there is no subcategory. It is quite easy to split the string into a list and save that list in a column but how on earth does one assign the first element of the list to one column and the second element (if it exists) to a second column. Surely there is an elegant easy way.

simplified sample

```
library(data.table)
library(stringi)
dt <- data.table(category.tag=c("toys/David", "toys/David", "toys/James", "toys", "toys", "toys/James"), transaction=1:6)
```

How do I create a third and fourth column: category, tag. Some of tag would be `NA`

I can do the following but it does not get me very far. I need a way to specify the first or the second element of the resultant list (as opposed to the whole list)

```
dt[, category:= strsplit(x = category.tag, split = "/") ]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just pushed two functions [`transpose()`](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1025) and [`tstrsplit()`](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1026) in *data.table v1.9.5*.

With this we can do:

```
require(data.table)
dt[, c("category", "tag") := tstrsplit(category.tag, "/", fixed=TRUE)]
#    category.tag transaction category   tag
# 1:   toys/David           1     toys David
# 2:   toys/David           2     toys David
# 3:   toys/James           3     toys James
# 4:         toys           4     toys    NA
# 5:         toys           5     toys    NA
# 6:   toys/James           6     toys James
```

`tstrsplit` is a wrapper for `transpose(strsplit(as.character(x), ...))`. And you can also pass `fill=.` to fill missing values with any other value than `NA`.

`transpose()` can also be used on *lists*, *data frames* and *data tables*.

Answer (score 4):

You could use `cSplit`

```
library(splitstackshape)
dt[, c("category", "tag") := cSplit(dt[,.(category.tag)], "category.tag", "/")]
dt
#    category.tag transaction category   tag
# 1:   toys/David           1     toys David
# 2:   toys/David           2     toys David
# 3:   toys/James           3     toys James
# 4:         toys           4     toys    NA
# 5:         toys           5     toys    NA
# 6:   toys/James           6     toys James
```

Comment: Is `cSplit` an abbreviation of `concat.split`?

Comment: I believe it's similar, with some added functionality

Comment: I love the one line easy elegance.

Comment: @Farrel, it's an alias, essentially. Several people were complaining that `concat.split` was too awkward to type, so when I was working on improving the function's efficiency, I changed the name to `cSplit`.

Comment: @AnandaMahto the reason that I asked, is that when I searched for it in Rdocumenctation.org under function, nothing came up.

Comment: @Farrel, The package version for "splitstackshape" at Rdocumentation is 1.2, but the present version is 1.4.2. `concat.split` is essentially Gabor's `read.table` approach, while `cSplit` is a *much* faster implementation using `strsplit`. By version 1.6, I plan to have moved over to `stri_split`, which would be even faster. Here's a (functional) [toy implementation](https://gist.github.com/mrdwab/3865d516fcc575d7099c) of where `cSplit` should be soon.

Comment: A little complication. In my simple example I only showed two possible fields with one separate being the hash. In actual fact it is  categories:subcategories/tag. Can I specify any of two separators so `sep = ":|/"` or what about cat is the first, subcategory is whatever comes after the : and tags are whatever comes over the slash /?

Comment: I decided to run two lines. The first line separates the category:subcategory from the tag which is after the /. Then I run a similar line that spits the category from the subcategory that uses the colon as the separator. It worked well.

Answer (score 2):

**1)** Try `read.table`

```
read <- function(x) read.table(text = x, sep  = "/", fill = TRUE, na.strings = "")
dt[, c("category", "tag") := read(category.tag)]
```

No extra packages are needed.

**2)** An alternative is to use `separate` in the tidyr package:

```
library(tidyr)
separate(dt, category.tag, c("category", "tag"), extra = "drop")
```

The above is with tidyr version 0.1.0.9000 from github. To install it ensure that the devtools R package is installed and issue the command: `devtools::install_github("hadley/tidyr")` .

**Update:** Incorporated Richard Scrivens' comment and minor improvements.  Added tidyr solution.

Comment: Absolutely wonderful. Now how should I decide who to award the "accepted" to. You or @RichardScriven. I like being introduced to new packages that may make my life easier with other problems but then again I assume there is an overhead when I use new packages instead of the functions that are already loaded.

Comment: getting `Error in strsplit(value, sep, ...) : unused argument (extra = "drop")`

Comment: I am using version 0.1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65554/discussion-between-farrel-and-g-grothendieck).

Answer (score 1):

Since you already have "stringi" loaded, you can also look at `stri_split_fixed` and the `simplify` argument:

```
setnames(cbind(dt, stri_split_fixed(dt$category.tag, "/", simplify = TRUE)), 
         c("V1", "V2"), c("category", "tag"))[]
#    category.tag transaction category   tag
# 1:   toys/David           1     toys David
# 2:   toys/David           2     toys David
# 3:   toys/James           3     toys James
# 4:         toys           4     toys    NA
# 5:         toys           5     toys    NA
# 6:   toys/James           6     toys James
```

Though I must admit I'm partial to `cSplit` :-)