# Conditional string split in data.table in R

Tags: r, regex, data.table

Based on this question: [Split text string in a data.table columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18154556/split-text-string-in-a-data-table-columns), I was wondering whether there is an efficient method to split the text string conditionally based on the contents of the row.

Suppose I have the following table:

```
Comments                  Eaten
001 Testing my computer   No
0026 Testing my fridge    No
Testing my car            Yes
```

and I would to have this:

```
ID   Comments             Eaten
001  Testing my computer  No
0026 Testing my fridge    No
NA   Testing my car       Yes
```

Where NA is empty.

Is this possible in data.table?

The comment should have an ID, but since this is optional, I only want to extract the ID's if and only if the comment starts with a number.

Comment: So you know that there supposed to be an ID and comments or this is supposed to be detected automatically?

Comment: It is optional to have an ID, but if it the comment starts with a number, then that should be automatically an ID.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This could be done using `tidyr`'s `extract` function which allows you to specify a regex pattern:

```
tidyr::extract(dt, Comments, c("ID", "Comments"), regex = "^(\\d+)?\\s?(.*)$")
#     ID            Comments Eaten
#1:  001 Testing my computer    No
#2: 0026   Testing my fridge    No
#3:   NA      Testing my car   Yes
```

You can add the argument `convert = TRUE` if you want the extracted columns to be converted to a more sensible type.

---

Another option using only base R and data.table would be

```
dt[grepl("^\\d+", Comments),                     # check if start with ID (subset)
   `:=`(ID = sub("^(\\d+).*", "\\1",Comments),   # extract ID from comments
        Comments = sub("^(\\d+)", "",Comments))  # delete ID from Comments
]
```

Though in this case the tidyr syntax seems a little easier to me. There may also be a way using data.table's `tstrsplit` function with a fancy lookaround regex.

Comment: `transpose(regmatches(x, regexec("^(\\d+)? ?(.*)", x)))` or similar, I guess. Not tested since OP's data is not copy-pastable...

Comment: R 3.4.0, also, has a `strcapture` function that could fit here -- `strcapture("^(\\d+)?\\s?(.*)$", dt$Comments, data.frame(ID = "", Comment = ""))`

Comment: @alexis_laz looks interesting but also a bit strange with those empty strings. I haven't upgraded to 3.4.0 yet