# detecting common characters in a list of strings, at specific positions

Tags: r, substring, strsplit

I have a very large dataset with many columns, exported from an application. The issue is that the file is "empty character" separated. Reading in the file with readLines yields a list of strings, each string with the same number of characters.

A possible way of determining the positions of the columns is checking whether each string, let s say at position 5, has an empty character. Therefore, can keep on searching starting from vector 1 until a non-empty character is found.

```
d <- data.frame("V1" = c(" f ggh", "aa hh", "a  qq" ), stringsAsFactors = 
F)


first.char <- function(col){
current <- 0
j <- 1
while(j <= length(d)){
tmp <- substr(d[j], col, col)
if(!grepl("^\\s*$", tmp)){
  current <- 1
  break}
j <- j+1
}
return(current)
}

row_dummies <- lapply( c(1:6), first.char) %>% unlist
```

This approach works but is very slow when scaling up (have a list of 1 million strings, each 1500 characters long). I also tried to transform each vector into a data.table and then use str split ([Split text string in a data.table columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18154556/split-text-string-in-a-data-table-columns)), but that seems to be even more inefficient, given that in most of the cases it is not necessary to check all rows.

Any suggestions or advice?

**UPDATE:**
The example above is too trivial. This one is a bit better:

```
text <- c("df ggh a a h h a  qq",
          "       aa  hh  ab qt",
          " fggh   aa hh  a    ")
```

The desired output is

```
 list( c("df ggh", "a a", "h h", "a",   "qq"),
       c(NA,       "aa",  "hh",  "ab",  "qq"),
       c(" fggh",  "aa",  "hh",  "a",   NA)

 )
```

str_locate_all works well, as it indicates where to split the strings:

```
cuts_in <- sapply(text, function(x) x %>%  str_locate_all(. , "\\s") ) 
cuts_in <- lapply(cuts_in,  data.table) # to data.table    
cuts_in <- rbindlist(cuts_in)
cuts_in <- cuts_in[, .N, by=start] 
cuts_in[ N==3 ,"start"]

   start
   1:     7
   2:    11
   3:    15
   4:    18
```

However, probably not the most efficient way (have 15 files, one million rows per file, each row has 1500 characters). For instance, there is no need to check the character at position 1 in rows 2 and 3 given that row 1 position 1 is not a space. read_table2 does not seem to be a solution either:

```
read_table2(text, col_names = FALSE)

  X1    X2    X3    X4    X5    X6    X7    X8   
 <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 df    ggh   a     a     h     h     a     qq   
2 aa    hh    ab    qt    NA    NA    NA    NA   
3 fggh  aa    hh    a     NA    NA    NA    NA
```

Comment: With the example  `read.table(text = d$V1, as.is = TRUE)`
 works.

Comment: yes, my example turns out to be too simple. One possible difference might be that I cant split at every empty character. Using read.table I get the following: Error in scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  : 
                line 2 did not have 79 elements

Comment: I think I'm a bit confused about the desired output; having the same number of characters per line doesn't mean you will have the same number of columns because of the different numbers of spaces. What do you want instead of what `read_table2` is giving you?

Comment: I don't know the number of columns ex-ante. I need to find that out, and also find out where they are. Because of how the data is exported, if a cell (in the database) is an NA, it is printed as " " in my txt file. This implies that I can get an idea about the columns by looking at " " column-wise. In the example above, the column split candidates are therefore at position 7, 11, 15, 18.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The situation you actually find yourself in is that you need to read a fixed width file and don't know where the columns are, which I didn't understand previously. You can try using `readr::read_fwf` for this. `fwf_empty` will look at some lines, by default 100, and try to figure out where the intersecting columns are. Depending on how many columns you expect to have in 1500 characters, you might need to increase n to get the right output.

```r
library(tidyverse)
text <- c("df ggh a a h h a  qq",
          "       aa  hh  ab qt",
          " fggh   aa hh  a    ")
read_fwf(text, fwf_empty(text, n = 100))
#> # A tibble: 3 x 5
#>   X1     X2    X3    X4    X5   
#>   <chr>  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
#> 1 df ggh a a   h h   a     qq   
#> 2 <NA>   aa    hh    ab    qt   
#> 3 fggh   aa    hh    a     <NA>
```

Alternatively, if you are already using `str_locate_all` and want to look at all the lines, you can convert the resulting locations into widths to use with `fwf_widths` by adding the start and end points and taking the differences. Note that you do not need to use `sapply` with `str_locate_all`, it's already vectorised. This is likely to be slower because it checks every row, and if you are not getting the correct output I would try increasing `n` first.

```r
locations <- text %>%
  str_locate_all("\\s") %>%
  map(~.[, 1]) %>%
  reduce(intersect)

widths <- c(1, locations, str_length(text[1])) %>% diff()

read_fwf(text, fwf_widths(widths))
#> # A tibble: 3 x 5
#>   X1     X2    X3    X4    X5   
#>   <chr>  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
#> 1 df ggh a a   h h   a     q    
#> 2 <NA>   aa    hh    ab    q    
#> 3 fggh   aa    hh    a     <NA>
```

<sup>Created on 2019-04-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: Updated now that I understand the question better

Answer (score 1):

How about `str_locate_all` from `stringr`:

```
library(stringr)

d <- data.frame("V1" = c(" f ggh", "aa hh", "a  qq" ), stringsAsFactors = 
F)

str_locate_all(d$V1, "\\s")


[[1]]
     start end
[1,]     1   1
[2,]     3   3

[[2]]
     start end
[1,]     3   3

[[3]]
     start end
[1,]     2   2
[2,]     3   3
```

But if you're trying to split it into different columns you can use a combo of `dplyr` and `tidyr` to do it all at once.

```
library(tidyverse)

d %>%
 mutate(V1 = str_trim(V1, side = "both")) %>%
 separate(V1, c("string_1", "string_2"), sep = "\\s+")

  string_1 string_2
1        f      ggh
2       aa       hh
3        a       qq
```

Comment: yes, works, then can split based on positions retrieved from intersecting the results. thanks

Comment: Updated the answer so that you split it as well with someone different functions.  Feel free to mark as answered so the question is closed ;)